# Cakephp routes and displaying data by id

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I'm getting my head around cake's routing, but am having trouble display data from one table in diff. views.

I have a news table with articles flagged by news_type_id. 
I have each routes set up to display views that call requestAction and list the news articles by specific news_type id.

```
//--index of news articles with news_type_id = 1
/section1/

//--index of news articles with news_type_id = 2 etc
/section2/
```

My routes are setup like:

```
Router::connect('/section1', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'section1'));
```

But the problem is as soon as I try:

```
Router::connect('/section1', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'section1'));
Router::connect('/section2', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'section2'));
```

... of course the actions route back to the top route (section1).

Can someone point out the obvious to me please?

Answer (score 0):

I would try :

```
Router::connect('/section1', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', array('mysection'=>'section1')));
Router::connect('/section2', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', array('mysection'=>'section2')));
```

and in the action I would get the mysection as parameter

Hope this could help

regards